# Simperium signin in landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, simperium

On iPhone and iPad I successfully added icon (project should contain square images icon.png and logo.png), and corrected LoginView.xib and LoginView-iPad.xib, so icon is shown in top of the screen.
But I discover that in landscape mode on iPad not only icon, but also login/psw fields are placed out of the screen. How i can change xib for authorization?

Answer (score 0):

The xib for authentication can be completely customized, and since the source code is open source, it can be modified as well. Having said that, landscape support should be built in. You can [track this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/issues/53).